# Java - Annotation Processing

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing

I have an annotation which marks classes that contain an inner class which implements a named interface.

Here's an example of how this annotation is used:

```
public interface Implementable {}

@Deserializable(Implementable.class)
public class ImplementableFactory {
    public static Implementable getImplementable() {
        return new Impl();
    }
    private class Impl implements Implementable {}
}
```

And here's the annotation itself:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public @interface Deserializable {
    Class value();
}
```

I'd like to do some annotation processing to ensure this contract. I've created an annotation processor class for that purpose:

```
public class DeserializableProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for(Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Deserializable.class)){
            TypeMirror expected = getDeserializableValue(element);
            if (expected != null) {
                Boolean found = false;
                for (Element enclosed : element.getEnclosedElements()) {
                    if (enclosed.getKind().equals(ElementKind.CLASS)) {
                        //This next bit doesn't compile.
                        //I'm looking for the same functionality.
                        if (expected.isAssignableFrom(enclosed)) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    String message = String.format("Classes marked with the Deserializable annotation must contain an inner class with implements the value of the annotation. %s does not contain a class which implements %s.",
                            element.getSimpleName().toString(),
                            expected.toString());
                    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, message);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private TypeMirror getDeserializableValue(Element element) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve similar functionality to Class::isAssignableFrom within reflection possible via annotation processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the aid of AbstractProcessor's protected processingEnvironment. It exposes an implementation of TypeUtils, a utility class that enables a lot of reflection functionality.

```
if (processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isAssignable(enclosed.asType(), expected)) {
    found = true;
    break;
}
```